# Parsing Suds SOAP complex data type into Python dict

Tags: python, soap, dictionary, suds

I have some data coming from a `SOAP` API using `Suds` which I need to parse in my `Python` script. Before I go off and write a parser (there is more than just this one to do):

1) <strike>Does anyone recognise what this is?</strike> It's the standard complex object datatype as returned by `Suds` [(documentation)](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/wiki/Original%20Documentation). Should have spotted that.

2) <strike>If so, is there an existing library that I can use to convert it to a Python dictionary?</strike> How do I parse this object into a Python dict? It seems I can pass a dictionary to Suds but can't see an easy way of getting one back out.

```
(ArrayOfBalance){
   Balance[] = 
      (Balance){
         Amount = 0.0
         Currency = "EUR"
      },
      (Balance){
         Amount = 0.0
         Currency = "USD"
      },
      (Balance){
         Amount = 0.0
         Currency = "GBP"
      },
 }
```

Comment: wow .. I can honestly say that in 20 years of doing this, I've never seen that form of serialization. Now I HAVE to know what that is lol. Can you give us a context for the data?

Comment: Glad it's not just me! It's the wallet balance response from [OKPay's API](https://www.okpay.com/en/developers/interfaces/functions/wallet-get-balance.html)

Comment: It seems like some self-made data structure :-\

Comment: As I suspected. It actually behaves like an object though. If you try and response.split(',') it gives `AttributeError: ArrayOfBalance instance has no attribute 'split'`. Gonna dig into the docs a bit more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a class method called `dict` in `suds.client.Client` class which takes a `sudsobject` as input and returns a Python `dict` as output. Check it out here: [Official Suds Documentation](https://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.client.Client-class.html#dict)

The resulting snippet becomes as elegant as this:

```
from suds.client import Client

# Code to obtain your suds_object here...

required_dict = Client.dict(suds_object)
```

You might also want to check out `items` class method ([link](https://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.client.Client-class.html#items)) in the same class which extracts items from suds_object similar to `items` method on `dict`.

Comment: now that i got it to a python dic how i can extract the information form it.

Comment: gives you a shallow copy which is worthless if you have nested sudsobjects

Comment: this worked for some of my requirements - thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

You can cast the object to `dict()`, but you still get the complex data type used by suds. So here are some helpful functions that I wrote just for the occasion:

```
def basic_sobject_to_dict(obj):
    """Converts suds object to dict very quickly.
    Does not serialize date time or normalize key case.
    :param obj: suds object
    :return: dict object
    """
    if not hasattr(obj, '__keylist__'):
        return obj
    data = {}
    fields = obj.__keylist__
    for field in fields:
        val = getattr(obj, field)
        if isinstance(val, list):
            data[field] = []
            for item in val:
                data[field].append(basic_sobject_to_dict(item))
        else:
            data[field] = basic_sobject_to_dict(val)
    return data


def sobject_to_dict(obj, key_to_lower=False, json_serialize=False):
    """
    Converts a suds object to a dict.
    :param json_serialize: If set, changes date and time types to iso string.
    :param key_to_lower: If set, changes index key name to lower case.
    :param obj: suds object
    :return: dict object
    """
    import datetime

    if not hasattr(obj, '__keylist__'):
        if json_serialize and isinstance(obj, (datetime.datetime, datetime.time, datetime.date)):
            return obj.isoformat()
        else:
            return obj
    data = {}
    fields = obj.__keylist__
    for field in fields:
        val = getattr(obj, field)
        if key_to_lower:
            field = field.lower()
        if isinstance(val, list):
            data[field] = []
            for item in val:
                data[field].append(sobject_to_dict(item, json_serialize=json_serialize))
        elif isinstance(val, (datetime.datetime, datetime.time, datetime.date)):
            data[field] = val.isoformat()
        else:
            data[field] = sobject_to_dict(val, json_serialize=json_serialize)
    return data


def sobject_to_json(obj, key_to_lower=False):
    """
    Converts a suds object to json.
    :param obj: suds object
    :param key_to_lower: If set, changes index key name to lower case.
    :return: json object
    """
    import json
    data = sobject_to_dict(obj, key_to_lower=key_to_lower, json_serialize=True)
    return json.dumps(data)
```

If there is an easier way, I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 4):

The right answer, as is often the case, is [in the docs](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/wiki/Original%20Documentation). The bits in (brackets) are objects which can contain other objects or types.

In this case we have an `ArrayOfBalance` object which contains a list of `Balance` types, each of which has the attributes of `Amount` and `Currency`.

These can all be referred to using `.` notation so the following one-liner does the trick.

```
balance = {item.Currency: item.Amount for item in response.Balance}
```

Comment: The link you provided is dead -- has it been rehosted somewhere else?

Comment: Bear in mind this was 5 years ago, and fedora hosting doesn't seem to exist any more. I've edited in a rescued copy of the docs, but the important parts are in the answer here.

Answer (score 4):

Found one [solution](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/15899/convert-suds-response-to-dictionary):

```
from suds.sudsobject import asdict

def recursive_asdict(d):
    """Convert Suds object into serializable format."""
    out = {}
    for k, v in asdict(d).iteritems():
        if hasattr(v, '__keylist__'):
            out[k] = recursive_asdict(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            out[k] = []
            for item in v:
                if hasattr(item, '__keylist__'):
                    out[k].append(recursive_asdict(item))
                else:
                    out[k].append(item)
        else:
            out[k] = v
    return out

def suds_to_json(data):
    return json.dumps(recursive_asdict(data))
```

If subs are just nested dict and list, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I was encountering a similar problem and had to read a suds response.
Suds response will be returned as a tuple consisting of objects.
len(response) will show you the number of objects contained in the suds response tuple.
In order to access the first object we need to give `response[0]`.

In IDLE if you type `>>>print response[0]` followed by a period '.' symbol you will get a popup showing the various objects that can be accessed from this level.

Example: if you type `response[0]`. it will bring a popup and show the Balance object so the command would now become `response[0].Balance`.

You can follow the same approach to get the list of objects under the subsequent levels

Answer (score 0):

The checkaayush's answer is not recursive so, it does not consider the nested objects.

Based on aGuegu Answer i did some changes to solve an issue when the suds object has dicts inside lists.

It works!

```
from suds.sudsobject import asdict

def recursive_asdict(d):
    """Convert Suds object into serializable format."""
    out = {}
    for k, v in asdict(d).items():
        if hasattr(v, '__keylist__'):
            out[k] = recursive_asdict(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            out[k] = []
            for item in v:
                if hasattr(item, '__keylist__'):
                    out[k].append(recursive_asdict(item))
                elif not isinstance(item, list):
                    out[k] = item
                else:
                    out[k].append(item)
        else:
            out[k] = v
    return out
```