# Convert suds objet in a python dict

Tags: python, api, soap, suds

I 'm using the `suds` library to consume a SOAP Api service.
The data receiving is a suds object. I need convert from suds object to python dict.

According the documentation the way to do this is

```
from suds.client import Client

# Code to obtain your suds_object here...

required_dict = Client.dict(suds_object)
```

But not work. The console show me this:

```
{'root': <suds.sudsobject.root object at 0x7fafdf98c700>}
```

If i add a print with type the result is a dict but in fact i don't get a dict

```
data...
```

Comment: [The same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581731/parsing-suds-soap-complex-data-type-into-python-dict/30066165)
Did you try all there?

Comment: [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412486/serializing-a-suds-object-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try the function at the very end of this link: [Serializing a suds object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412486/serializing-a-suds-object-in-python)

Addresses both recursive suds objects, but also suds.sax.text.Text